# Why does the number 312213 follow the number211213

Tags: sequence

In a number sequence of 1, 11, 21, 1112, 3112, 211213, why is the next number 312213?

Comment: This is a classic question, follow the link above.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but it is a duplicate of a question that was closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Go here at $5$:$33$, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5P-f5arPXE

Answer (score 4):

This looks like

> A sorted version of the [Look-and-Say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)

In this version

> You sort the digits first, then count left to right. So $211213$ sorted is $111223$ which has 
> $3$ $1$s, 
> $2$ $2$s and 
>  $1$ $3$ which gives the next number $312213$